# SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema() method doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I do the following:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("... my connection string ...");

dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from items", conn);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;

DataTable schemaTable = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.FillSchema(schemaTable, SchemaType.Source);
```

However, there are no rows in the schemaTable. dataAdapter.Fill() work.

Comment: `SchmemaType.Source` I think should be `SchemaType.Mapped`

Comment: You just need to add `dataAdapter.Fill(schemaTable);` to fill the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `FillSchema` does.

It takes the DataTable passed in (with no row and no column) and builds the schema adding the columns with infos about size, type etc... corresponding to the table that will be returned by the `SelectCommand`.
It doesn't fill the passed in table with records.

Infact, if you look at the Columns count after the call to `FillSchema` you will find that your `schemaTable` has been 'built' with columns matching the `items` table.

So, what is the use for a FillSchema call considering that a Fill call, equally fills the table with its columns names and types? Well, `FillSchema` is used to prepare the table passed in for the following `Fill` with some properties that otherwise are not loaded by the Fill call. For example, suppose that your `items` table has an `AutoIncrement` column. This property is not available on the the matching DataColumn after the call to Fill. But, if you pass to Fill, the table prepared by FillSchema, that property is available.

If you want just the infos about the columns of your table you need a different approach

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.......)
{
    con.Open();
    DataTable schema = con.GetSchema("Columns", new string[] {null, null, "items"});
    foreach(DataRow row in schema.Rows)
        Console.WriteLine("TABLE:" + row.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME") + 
                          " COLUMN:" + row.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME"));
}
```

or in a more standard way

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.......)
{
    con.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                                      WHERE TABLE_NAME='items' 
                                      AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'yourDBNameHere'", con);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(reader);
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      ..... catalog, name, ordinal_position, column_default etc....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `FillSchema` method retrieves the schema from the database using the `SelectCommand`. A FillSchema creates a DataTable with the PrimaryKey and Constraints properties, adds the columns to the DataColumnCollection and configures the necessary DataColumn properties. This method doesn't fill the datatable with rows, it only applies the schema. use the `Fill`method to do this.